# using /dev/shm on vagrant - PERMISSION ERROR / MacOSX

Tags: php, symfony, caching, vagrant, shared-memory

I'm using Vagrant to develop in Linux Ubuntu enviroment on my MacOSX.

Working with Symfony2. Everything is fine with db and coding.

When i try to clear cache and install assets, it's looking like it's done but i could not use any cache i think because my assets are not changed.

So, i have tried to change cache directory to `/dev/shm`.

Refreshed my page and looked to that directory to see any directory created, i saw the directory created successfully by www-data user and group. So php-fpm must created that directory, so it works?

I have tried to generating assets again, but i get a permission error...

Chaging cache directory:

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    if (in_array($this->environment, array('dev', 'test'))) {
        return '/dev/shm/appname/cache/' .  $this->environment;
    }

    return parent::getCacheDir();
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    if (in_array($this->environment, array('dev', 'test'))) {
        return '/dev/shm/appname/logs';
    }

    return parent::getLogDir();
}
```

My scenario:

The files are created by www-data. When i try to install assets on console (terminal);

```
php app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

php-cli or php-cgi works with another user and has not permitted to modify that files.

What can i do? I'm stuck!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do the same thing with a Ubuntu host. In the end what I did in the end was create app/cache as a directory link to /run/shm/sf-cache.

This is from the setup bash script I run during provisioning....

```
# create the cache path
sudo mkdir -p /run/shm/sf-cache/
sudo chmod 777 /run/shm/sf-cache

# Copy over the rest of the files (from /vagrant to /var/www/sf-project/)
/vagrant/provision/resync_files.sh

# Setup the log folder
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/sf-project/app/logs

cd /var/www/sf-project

# Link the Cache folder to the folder in the ram drive.
sudo ln -s /run/shm/sf-cache/ app/cache
```

But you'll notice the only way to do it (at least for me) was to create a copy of the files that reside in /vagrant in /var/www/ as /var/www is on the local filesystem, /vagrant isn't, its on the host.

With PHPStorm its not a problem as I just share the /var/www/sf-project folder via samba and then map it as a folder. On my ubuntu host (I'm in the process of migrating from Windows to Ubuntu), I mount the samba share and then create a directory link to the mount point and then in PHPStorm setup the deployment server to deploy it to the local folder which because its the samba share, copies it straight into the /var/www/sf-project folder.

I appreciate its more work if you don't use PHPStorm, but that's the way I solved that particular issue. I found this easier than trying to move the cache folder, which we had the added complication that not every developer was using a Vagrant box, so I couldn't simply change the code without breaking their systems.